# How to remove special character from Json without parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json

I want to remove some special character from `json` without parsing
the `json` into `object`.

Parsing would result into error that is why i wanted to do without `json.parse()`.

**below is my json:**

```
{
    "id":324,
    "name":"first",
    "body":{
        "sbody": "<p>\\\The New Stroy\\\</p>"
    }
}
```

**desired output:**

```
{
    "id":324,
    "name":"first",
    "body":{
        "sbody": "<p> The New Stroy </p>"
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the syntax, what you appear to have is an object, not JSON. Therefore any use of `JSON.parse` is irrelevant.

Comment: What are those special character? Just slashes? Repeated slashes? Invalid escape sequences?

Comment: Why would you not want to parse it? To ensure you know you're looking at a string you'll end up with a parser.

Comment: Is your input a response from ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your input is a string and the error you are getting is when using `JSON.parse`.

Try this

```js
var response = '{"sbody": "<p>\\\The New Stroy\\\</p>"}';
response = response.replace(/\\/g, "");
var obj = JSON.parse(response);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `.replace` on your string:

```js
var string = '{"id":324,"name":"first","body":{"sbody":"<p>\\\The New Stroy\\\</p>"}}';

string = string.replace(/\\/g,'');

console.log(string);

//{"id":324,"name":"first","body":{"sbody":"<p>The New Stroy</p>"}}
```

The reason the pattern is `/\\/` is because `\` is used to escape characters. With a single `\` we end up escaping the `/`. What we need to do here is escape the escape character to turn it into a literal string character: `\\`.

The `g` after the pattern means to search for the pattern "globally" in the string, so we replace all instances of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {
    "id":324,
    "name":"first",
    "body":{
        "sbody": "<p>\\\The New Stroy\\\</p>"
    }
}

// Convert object to string
var str = JSON.stringify(obj);

// Remove \ from the string
var convertedStr= str.replace(/\\/g,'');

// Convert updated string back to object
var newObj = JSON.parse(convertedStr);
```